# Why simple_one_for_one workers can share the same Child Spec Id?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I define simple_one_for_one worker spec for one supervisor named band_supervisor， and the child spec id is `jam_musician`:

```
  init([]) ->
    {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 3, 60},
    [{jam_musician,
    {musicians, start_link, []},
    temporary, 1000, worker, [musicians]}
    ]}};
```

musicians module is:

```
-module(musicians).
-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/2, stop/1]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2,
handle_info/2, code_change/3, terminate/2]).

-record(state, {name="", role, skill=good}).
-define(DELAY, 750).

start_link(Role, Skill) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, Role}, ?MODULE, [Role, Skill], []).

stop(Role) -> gen_server:call(Role, stop).
```

and I can create many workers by:

```
3> supervisor:start_child(band_supervisor, [drum, good]).
Musician Arnold Ramon, playing the drum entered the room
{ok,<0.696.0>}
3> supervisor:start_child(band_supervisor, [guitar, good]).
Musician Wanda Perlstein, playing the guitar entered the room
{ok,<0.698.0>}
```

I notice that all workers have the same Child spec Id: `jam_musician`

You know other type workers must has the unique child id, Right ?

Comment: Could you post your code for the `musicians` module, please? It looks like you are registering the child processes with the same name.

Comment: Yes, your code please for the supervisor module as well. Something is wrong as you cannot get an `already_started` from a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor.

Comment: @Isac have updated , the child spec id can be duplicated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child specification identifier will be the same for `simple_one_for_one` supervisors since there is only one child type and many child instances (workers) of this type.

From the [`supervisor` behaviour docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html):

> Notice that when the restart strategy is `simple_one_for_one`, the list of child specifications must be a list with one child specification only. (The child specification identifier is ignored.) No child process is then started during the initialization phase, but all children are assumed to be started dynamically using `start_child/2`.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you wrote the start_link function of the child process (I assume it is a gen_server) as:

```
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local,Name}, ?MODULE, [], []).
```

This not only calls the init/1 function but also registers the process using the atom Name.

Therefore any new child started in a second moment will try to register inside the erlang node using a name already taken by the first child.

In order to avoid such name clashing you should use something like:

```
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).
```

So that no child will have a registered name and you will have no clashing.

If you really need to register every child an option may consist in the use of [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc).

Comment: That will generate an error and not an `already_started` return. You will **only** get an `already_started` if you do a `restart_child/2` with **not** a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor and you try to start an id that is already started. You cannot get it with a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor where the id is ignored.

Comment: My last question is : Need I define the child spec in init callback function first , if I want to start the child with the spec later ?

Comment: I am not following you any more. I don't understand what you want to achieve here

Comment: In a `simple_one_for_one` you must define the child spec as it is used for all children and you do not give it when starting a child. In all other cases you do not need to give it as you must explicitly give a child spec when you call `supervisor:start_child/2`. The supervisor will automatically start the children with child specs returned in the `init/1` callback. You can then add children using `supervisor:start_child/2`.